# Add elements of lists where dates match (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have 2 lists:

```
vals = [1,2,3,4]
dates = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
```

where dates are in Python's datetime format.

Then, given another set of lists:

```
vals_2 = [1, 1, 2, 2]
dates_2 = [t5,t6,t7,t8]
```

It could be that `t6` = `t1`, etc.

Now, I would like to add `vals` and `vals_2` where the dates match (so add `vals[i]` and `vals_2[j]` if `dates[i] == dates_2[j]`).

I would like an efficient solution.

**My idea so far:**
Put vals in a Pandas dataframe, then put vals_2 in a separate dataframe and merge the two on the date key?

**Question:** Is this a good (/the best) idea? I am not sure exactly how to deal with this given the datetime format etc., so some pointers on how to get started would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You could also use a simple dictionary instead that maps date to value from `vals` or `vals_2`

Comment: You said that it could be that `t6 == t1`, but in this case you wouldn't add the corresponding values because they do not have the same index `i`, right?

Comment: @IanS yes that is a great point, thanks for correcting this. I mean add vals[i] to vals_2[j] if dates[i] == dates_2[j] for all i in the range 0 to len(vals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the lines of what you suggested:

```
import datetime as dt

vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dates = [dt.date(2016,1,n) for n in range(1, 5)]
vals_2 = [1, 1, 2, 2]
dates_2 = [dt.date(2016,1,n) for n in range(3, 7)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'vals': vals})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates_2, 'vals': vals_2})

>>> df1.merge(df2, on='date', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])

         date  vals_1  vals_2
0  2016-01-03       3       1
1  2016-01-04       4       1
```

You can also convert the dates into Timestamps and then do the comparison, which should be slightly faster:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.date)
```

**Timings with 40k records**

Pandas using datetime objects.

```
%timeit df1.merge(df2, on='date', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
1 loops, best of 3: 10.2 s per loop
```

Pandas using timestamps.

```
%timeit df1.merge(df2, on='date', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
1 loops, best of 3: 9.1 s per loop
```

Comment: What I like about this is that it can handle cases where the dates do not intersect. I guess you could then turn NaNs (which would arise from non-overlapping dates) into zeros for the addition part.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to get `vals_3` where i is an index and `vals_3[i] = vals[i] + vals_2[i]` if `dates[i]` equals `dates_2[i]`, you can do :

```
vals_3 = [vals[idx]+vals_2[idx] for idx, date in enumerate(dates) if date == dates_2[idx]]
```